# Find out 0 position from string in hive

Tags: regex, hive, position, patindex

I want to know the position of the data which doesn't start with 0. 
Like below example, in first row first digits are 00 and it returns the 3 position as non zero values start from 3 position

```
member_id          values

008507743          3     
017521344          2    
040324598          2
```

SQL CODE:-

```
select  member_id,patindex('%[^0]%',MEMBER_ID)as Index_value  from tablename
```

The above thing in sql and I just want the same in hive and unable to find out the solution for the same.
Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT INSTR(member_id, regexp_extract(member_id, '[^0]', 0)) from tablename
```

From [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

> instr(string str, string substr) :- Returns the position of the first occurrence of substr in str. Returns null if either of the arguments are null and returns 0 if substr could not be found in str. Be aware that this is not zero based. The first character in str has index 1.

***Explanation***

`regexp_extract` returns the first number/alphabet that is not `0`.

`instr` returns the index of the found element from `regexp_extract`